# Rotational Energy Requirements: Rotating at hinge vs Rotating at midpoint

Tags: energy, rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics

**The number of upvotes on comment #1 distresses me. Nobody listens anymore.**

There are two scenarios *(which I invented, are not homework, are not vague/trivial, and aim at a legitimate concept which I can't describe any other way)*.

**In the first, a motor rotates a rod exactly where it hinges. In the second, a cog is welded to the midpoint of the rod and a motor distanced the length of the cog's radius causes the rod to spin, placing strain on the midsection and not the pivot.** Please assume the rod has no real weight (is not affected by gravity).

The question: Which scenario would require less energy in making the rod turn a revolution or are they the same?

For bonus points *(which is not exclusively homework-language, it is my language)*: Is there a rough equation to estimate the added energy cost that uses the cog-radius:percent-on-rod ratio?

Please don't erroneously flag my question as homework. I'm just trying to understand this better. This example I created is the best way to articulate the underlying concept. I'm not certain, but it appears that rotation requires more work the closer to the hinge you are but that might be wrong.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Would it take less energy to rotate a cog welded onto a rod's midpoint or rotate at the rod's pivot?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/657475/would-it-take-less-energy-to-rotate-a-cog-welded-onto-a-rods-midpoint-or-rotate)

Comment: Please don't repost questions. Instead, edit the original (as you have done) and it might get reopened.

Comment: *Might* is the operative word. Look, I mean no offense but using this site was a mistake.

Comment: Questions must be in the scope of this site's policy. For homework(-like) – note that it must not necessarily be actual homework, but includes any questions asking for a specific computation – this means that it should be a *conceptual* question. See [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) for more information. For questions about this site, please use the [meta]. Thanks!

Comment: Tis conceptual. I did use an example but it's the best way a lay person like myself can communicate this fundamental mystery about rotation I have. Take it away and I'll have no way of asking.

Comment: Your question is still a bit vague. Requires less energy for what? Do you mean less energy to make the rod go a full revolution, or  less energy per revolution of motor? @KuraiFIN

Comment: @BrainStrokePatient I've edited for "make the rod turn a full revolution" but honestly have no idea what difference that makes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean less energy to make the rod go a full revolution, then it's scenario A. Because in scenario A the rod makes a full revolution whenever the motor makes a full revolution. While it takes multiple motor revolutions to make the rod go through a full revolution once in scenario B. In this case the ratio of the energy cost would just be the number of revolutions the motor needs to go through in scenario B to make the rod rotate once.

If you mean less energy per revolution of motor, then both are doing the same amount of work and expending the same amount of energy for one single revolution of the motor.

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that may be the case but your elaboration was very useful!

Comment: Actually, for energy used by motor, doesn't scenario B benefit from the lever/fulcrum effect? @BrainStrokePatient

Comment: @KuraiFIN If the point of application is further from the fulcrum, then yes less force is required for the same torque. But that is not the same as work done. Work is still the same because the point of application of force moves a greater distance (but the same angle) when it is farther from the fulcrum.